# How to get Date only on a DateTime attribute? working on a calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working with a Calendar and I think that calendar deals only with date without a time.

Note: *requested_date is a **DateTime** Attribute*. I want to get all reservations with requested date and covert it to date only:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def myprofile
    @reservation = Reservation.all
    @resv_by_date = @reservation.group_by(&:requested_date) <-- make requested_date to date only
end
```

**myprofile.html.erb**

```
<div id="admin">
<%= calendar do |date| %>
    <%= date.day %><br>
        <%  @resv_by_date.each do |reservation| %>
        <%= reservation.requested_date.to_date  %><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

[*(this month 'May') requested_date is existing on my database*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZZzV.png)
[image: (this month 'May') requested_date is existing on my database]

[*image output after the solution of the 1st answer*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TKsF.png)
[image: image output after the solution of the 1st answer]

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyE Sqlite.. my only problem is on the controller and i just want to get the date from a DateTime attribute..

Comment: @AnthonyE 
 
i update myprofile.html.erb and see new uploaded output image.. there is a problem with the loop.

Comment: Correcting grammar and improve formatting. displaying screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use a `group` on your ActiveRecord relation not `group_by` which is a Ruby method.

Also, the method to get a `Date` from a `DateTime` object is `datetime.to_date`:

```
@reservations_by_date = Reservation.select(:requested_date).group(:requested_date)

@reservations_by_date.each { |reservation| puts reservation.requested_date.to_date }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd advice you to try to group the data in the DB already (using `group`) for performance reasons instead of ruby code (`group_by`). But in your specific case it seems that you indeed need to retrieve *all* reservations in the given time period (e.g. month) and just group them by the date so that you can display all of them in the calendar view. In that case, you indeed have to group in ruby code.

You can do that simply by updating the block in `group_by`:

```
@reservations_by_date = Reservation.all.group_by { |res| res.requested_date.to_date }
```

Note that most probably you'll want to narrow down the select only to the given time period (e.g. the displayed month) first, using `where` conditions, I skipped that part from this answer.

The grouping above will create a hash of the reservations where the keys will be the dates (not datetimes) and the values will be arrays of reservations in the given date. In the calendar view, you can simply browse once you've accessed them using the date key:

```
<% calendar do |date| %>
  <%= date.day %><br>
  <% @reservations_by_date[date].each do |reservation| %>
    <%= reservation.name ... or whatever %><br>
<% end %>
```